# Отправка GET запроса и получение ответа - Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Не смотря на простое юзабилити либы `Retrofit` я все равно не могу без проблем с ней работать. Есть ссылка

```
http://chat.pareto-marketing.ru/getform.php
```

Куда надо передать ключ

```
?key=1234
```

Так вот я создаю класс

```
public class App63 extends Application
{
    private static Api63 api63;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://www.chat.pareto-marketing.ru/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        api63 = retrofit.create(Api63.class);
    }

    public static Api63 getApi()
    {
        return api63;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface Api63 
{
    @GET("getform.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> getData(@Query("key") String key);
}
```

И вот кусок кода

```
public void get() {
    Call<ResponseBody> response = App63.getApi().getData("1234");
    response.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> p1, Response<ResponseBody> response)
            {
                try
                {
                    buildList(response.body().string());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {}
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> p1, Throwable p2)
            {
            }
    });
}
```

Но вот только я получаю вылет с таким логом

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

`Retrofit` я "собрал" руками из отдельных библиотек. Сначала я скачал jar с их официального сайта, положил в `libs`, но происходил вылет, так как `Retrofit` не находил `okhttp3`. Я скачал `okhttp3.jar` и комбинировал обе либы. Далее кто-то там ругался на отсутствие `okio` я и ее также подключил. В итоге получился такой jar-комбайн. При запросе `GET` без передачи параметров проблем нет. А вот сейчас впервые понадобилось их передать и вот. Вылет

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54167/discussion-on-question-by-flippy--get-----retro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, если это запрос, то надо установить @GET

```
public interface Api63{
@GET("getform.php")
Call<ResponseBody> getData(@Query("key") String key);}
```

В baseUrl поместите

> "http://www.chat.pareto-marketing.ru/?"

Также не забывайте поместить в AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Должно работать.

Comment: Запросы бываю разные, а не только GET

Comment: Та же ошибка. :(